# I need to write the English boys name "Jules" in Chinese.

Tags: translation

I am writing this on a gift for someone and I need to be sure the Chinese characters are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Jules---朱尔斯,that's it,every time you need to check out a Chinese name,you can go search www.baidu.com